# ACR cloud return recent results

Tags: acrcloud

I'm using broadcast monitoring to return the current playing song for a radio station website by using the live result and calling with

```
echo $song[0]['metadata']['music'][0]['artists'][0]['name'] . ' - ';
echo" <a href='https://open.spotify.com/track/{$song[0]['metadata']['music']
[0]['external_metadata']['spotify']['track']['id']}' target='_blank'>
{$song[0]['metadata']['music'][0]['title']}</a> ";
```

I'd like a dynamic response to display the songs played on that day, without having to manually update the call - I can only see how to return a specified date.

Is this possible? For example, displaying the last 20 songs for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the monitoring result (getting from callback url) to the mysql database,

then display the last 20 songs (getting from mysql) in another web url.

Comment: Thanks - turns out I can set the response to a limit without a database

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by limiting number of responses to specified number using ?limit=xx